# Term for the modified part of a prepositional complement

Tags: syntax, terminology, phrase-structure, prepositions

A [prepositional complement](http://slb-ltsu.hull.ac.uk/awe/index.php?title=Prepositional_complement) is the noun phrase that follows a preposition. So, given sentences like

> John saw the woman with an umbrella.

and

> John saw the moon with a telescope.

The prepositional phrases are **with an umbrella** and **with a telescope**. And the prepositional complements are **an umbrella** and **a telescope**. In the first sentence, the modified phrase is an NP, and in the second, it is a verb.

What is(are) the term(s) for parts modified by these PPs?

Comment: 'Receiver' is not a grammatical term; I assume you mean 'modify'; and what you call a 'complement' is called an 'object'. Prepositional phrases can modify other phrases or whole clauses, as well as nouns. _With an umbrella_ modifies _the woman_, a noun phrase; it's identificational, describing the woman. _With a telescope_ modifies _saw the moon_, a verb phrase; it's instrumental, describing the means used. _He saw the woman with a telescope_ is ambiguous between these two meanings.

Comment: Another useful term is *scope*, which more or less means "that which is modified", so the scope of the prepositional phrases is different between the two examples: in the first one, the scope of *with an umbrella* is *(the) woman*; in the second one, the scope of *with a telescope* is *(John) saw the moon*. Here is an interesting article about the scope of adverbial clauses, although it uses many technical terms at some point: [Adverbial clauses, Functional Grammar, and the change from sentence grammar to discourse-text grammar](http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/circulo/no4/kwee.htm).

Comment: @jlawler: I did mean 'modify'. I'll fix that in the question. I keep coming across conflicting definitions of "prepositional complement" and "prepositional object". I'll happily defer to you on that, but I won't change it in this question because I'll also have to change the URL I link to.

Comment: I also usually hear prepositional object, but I think prepositional complement is perhaps equally clear? The only alternative interpretation would have to be "a complement to the verb that happens to be a prepositional phrase" (which is not what you mean). This unwanted interpretation is not possible with "object".

Comment: Outside the specific reference to a [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf) as a noun clause with a grammatical relation to the predicate, I think the word _complement_ is too vague to be of use. What does it add to distinguish the consituent it labels? Why call it something vague like _complement_ if you can call it a noun phrase or an object and be specific?

Comment: As for _scope_, that is a term more normally reserved for Operators -- [Negatives, Modals, Quantifiers](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) -- which always have some focussed element (usually stressed) that they are negating, modalizing, or quantifying. Negative Polarity Items are used to track negative scope (and strength), for instance. When scopes get twisted about by syntax, you get Q-Q ambiguities like _Every boy read some book_ or Q-Neg ambiguities like _Every boy didn't leave_. That's quite specific enough already, without adding another sense, thank you.

Comment: I agree that *object* is preferable. I believe *scope* is also used outside negatives etc., and don't think there is any ambiguity there, nor any other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People had already given me the answer I was looking for, but as comments to the question. I'll just paste them here for posterity, and mark the question answered.

**jlawler:** 'Receiver' is not a grammatical term; I assume you mean 'modify'; and what you call a 'complement' is called an 'object'. Prepositional phrases can modify other phrases or whole clauses, as well as nouns. *With an umbrella* modifies *the woman*, a noun phrase; it's identificational, describing the woman. *With a telescope* modifies *saw the moon*, a verb phrase; it's instrumental, describing the means used. *He saw the woman with a telescope* is ambiguous between these two meanings.

**Cerberus:** Another useful term is *scope*, which more or less means "that which is modified", so the scope of the prepositional phrases is different between the two examples: in the first one, the scope of *with an umbrella* is *(the) woman*; in the second one, the scope of *with a telescope* is *(John) saw the moon*. Here is an interesting article about the scope of adverbial clauses, although it uses many technical terms at some point: [Adverbial clauses, Functional Grammar, and the change from sentence grammar to discourse-text grammar](http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/circulo/no4/kwee.htm).

Comment: An interesting distinction appears in the Jlawler's and Cerberus' comments above. Jlawler states that "with the telescope" can be a modifier of the verb phrase "saw the moon", whereas Cerberus comments that "with the telescope" can have "(John) saw the moon" in its scope. In my view, Cerberus' comment has got it right. The PP "with the telescope" modifies the entire clause "John saw the moon", not just the VP "saw the moon".