# What are the terms for a) the constituent before a preposition and b) the constituent after a preposition?

Tags: terminology, prepositions

Consider phrases such as these:

- "Joe from France"
- "Transport of wheat"
- "Walking to Berlin

Are there specific grammatical terms for a) the constituent that occurs immediately before a preposition and b) the constituent that occurs immediately after a preposition?

Comment: see http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/term-for-the-modified-part-of-a-prepositional-complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word in front of a preposition can be the *head* that governs the prepositional phrase, but it doesn't have to be. Only the position *after* a preposition marks a special syntactic function; that is called a **prepositional object** or the **object of a proposition**, like *Berlin, France, wheat* in your examples.

Comment: Yeah, the front and back words are bracketed differently: [Joe [from France]], [transport [of wheat]], [walking [to Berlin]]. We say that the prepositional phrases _from France, of wheat, to Berlin_ are **constituents**, in that they're complete units in themselves and modify as a unit.